# How to show alert dialog in between the video conference call

Tags: android, android-studio, android-alertdialog, video-conferencing

Actually I'm making an app,in which I want to give video conference option and want to show some data in between the video call through alert dialog. Is it possible to show the alert dialog in between the call

Answer (score 0):

you have to ping it by push notification and get response to popup or use webrtc to realtime data exhange

Comment: In ciscowebex when we are in video call, we can go to another activity which is containing the chat options,likewise it is possible to do some more stuffs there